# Handling a python script with telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have a python program that has nothing to do with telegram (it's a web scraping app).
It has a while loop that may take a while to end.

I would like to be able to start my python app by sending something like '/start' to my telegram bot and then terminate my program by sending '/stop'

I already have the telegram bot, and I am able to interact with it. It can start and stop the polling easily.
Starting the web scraping app is easy as well, I use the start handler for that, with something like :

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    my_web_scraping_app()
```

But I can seem to make it stop with another handler.
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: does your web scraping app have a stop method?

Comment: No, just a break case that will be always eventually be reached, but potentially after a long time